# Filter array with unique values

Tags: javascript

This has been posted time and time again and after reading them all, I still don't know what I'm doing wrong. I understand there are so many ways to do this and I get the feeling I've mixed them up.

I'm trying to get the uniques value from serviceType so rather than having Cars Now, Cars Now, Vans Now, I should only have Cars No, Vans Now.

See attached code

```js
const preFilteredRows = [
{
"serviceType": "Cars Now",
"applictionType": "Direct",
"wheelType": "4x4"
},
{
"serviceType": "Cars Now",
"applictionType": "web",
"wheelType": "2x4"
},
,
{
"serviceType": "Vans Now",
"applictionType": "Direct",
"wheelType": "2x4"
}
]

let tempArr = [];
preFilteredRows.forEach(row => {
    if(row.values[serviceType].length == 1) tempArr.push(row.values[serviceType][0])
})
/* return [...new Set(tempArr)] */
newServiceSet = [...new Set(tempArr)]
console.log(newServiceSet)
```

UPDATE:
Thank you all so much for your feedback, I really do appreciate your help with my learning.

One part I forgot to add to my question and just realise is, I not only need the uniques values, but I also need them displayed like the below image so each value has a value and a label. I don't need the count anymore.

[image]

Comment: None of them have the `.values` your if statement checks for

Comment: I don't understand what you think you're doing in your `forEach()`; I *think* that `row.values[serviceType].length == 1` should be `row.serviceType.length > 0`; but honestly I don't really know (as I said) what you're testing for (and this is why comments are good things).

Comment: Your updates to the question should be separate question. Please create a separate thread for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want

```
[
  "Cars Now",
  "Vans Now"
]
```

Do a map and filter and then do your spread operator for unique values.

```js
const preFilteredRows = [
{
"serviceType": "Cars Now",
"applictionType": "Direct",
"wheelType": "4x4"
},
{
"serviceType": "Cars Now",
"applictionType": "web",
"wheelType": "2x4"
},
,
{
"serviceType": "Vans Now",
"applictionType": "Direct",
"wheelType": "2x4"
}
]

let tempArr = preFilteredRows.map(row => row.serviceType) // map extracts the serviceType
           .filter(service => service); // filter removes any undefined/empty values

newServiceSet = [...new Set(tempArr)] // only keeps unique values

console.log(newServiceSet)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

- `map` - to map each object from array to its `serviceType` property value
- `new Set` - to get all unique values from the array generated in above step

```js
const preFilteredRows = [
  { "serviceType": "Cars Now", "applictionType": "Direct", "wheelType": "4x4" },
  { "serviceType": "Cars Now", "applictionType": "web", "wheelType": "2x4" },
  { "serviceType": "Vans Now", "applictionType": "Direct", "wheelType": "2x4" }
];

const unique_types = [...new Set(preFilteredRows.map(item => item.serviceType))];
console.log(unique_types);
```

Answer (score 0):

A mix of map and filter would be do this job.

```js
const preFilteredRows = [
{
"serviceType": "Cars Now",
"applictionType": "Direct",
"wheelType": "4x4"
},
{
"serviceType": "Cars Now",
"applictionType": "web",
"wheelType": "2x4"
},
,
{
"serviceType": "Vans Now",
"applictionType": "Direct",
"wheelType": "2x4"
}
]
const n = [...new Set( preFilteredRows.map(obj => obj.serviceType)) ].filter(f => f);

console.log(n)
```